# Getting an "Access Denied" error when I reload my React app on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am working on a React app that's running on AWS Amplify. My React app is using the react-router-dom library to route to different components. After running amplify publish in the CLI, at the root of the app (obktraining.com) everything is fine in the browser, I can also route to other components in the app just fine as well. But when I refresh my browser while I am on a route (obktraining.com/menu), I get an Access Denied error message.

I have found other posts about similar issues regarding rewrites and redirects in Amplify, but the solutions given do not work for me.

Here is an image of the error: [image]

My Amplify app rewrites & redirects : [image]

Again, the error only displays when I refresh on a route (obktraining.com/menu or obktraining.com/drinks) not on obktraining.com. Is the issue being caused by the react-router-dom library or is it an issue with Amplify settings? I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @justing were you able to resolve this with the provided solutions below? Because I have the same issue, but when I tried the solution below, I cannot reach my login page. It appears to be a blank screen.

Comment: @AzherAleem try `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>` instead of `</^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`. It should work fine.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Comment: @UsamaTahir, Thanks, I was able to resolve this and added my solution as an answer below.

Comment: Adding the redirect is still not working for my project. I have added the source address pattern as specified but still I'm getting the XML permission denied error

Answer (score 34):

I have been facing the same error since days.The error is being caused by the amplify settings. The solution is simple,
Edit your Rewrites and redirects by adding a new rule.

*source address = </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>*

*target address = /index.html*

*status = 200 (Rewrite)*

*Country code can be left blank*

Save and try refreshing your app again. It should probably work.

use this for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Comment: This worked well, thanks! Can you explain why this worked? I read the reference but I still don't completely understand what happened here.

Comment: This worked for me as well! Remember to NOT put the / in front of the source address provided, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I tried this and now my app loads but it just loads to a white screen and only has the index.html contents.

Comment: @cmcnphp yes it only loads index.html content

Comment: white screen went away when i replaced "index.html" with. "/"

Answer (score 25):

[image: This is where you can find Redirects on your Amplify Menu]

Then you can just put in (as Dhruv Godambe posted above)

</^((?!.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$).)*$/>

as the Source address and

/index.html as your target address

[image: This is what it looks like in AWS]

Comment: but this only loads for me the index.html content on any route

Answer (score 22):

You can navigate to 'rewrites and redirects' in your app from AWS Amplify console and click on edit and select open text editor, and add this piece of code in your array(if present) else put the array braces around it.

```
{
        "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>",
        "target": "/index.html",
        "status": "200",
        "condition": null
}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Comment: this only loads for me the index.html page and not the other routes and if i remove this.. the access denied error will come up again

Comment: Are you sure? Adding this helps load all other pages as well.

Comment: This seems some exceptional case to me only to me...can you please share your calendly link and help me please

Comment: I do not have an index.html file. I have App.tsx file. How to fix in that case?

Comment: Thanks. You need to add source like this `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json|webmanifest)$)([^.]+$)/>` if you see an error like `Manifest: Line 1, column 1, Syntax error.`

Comment: @Dreamer A little late, but for anyone else reading, your TypeScript project with an App.tsx file will still be compiled and built to a collection of static files with an index.html in it.

Answer (score 4):

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html

---

I have faced the same problem.
I was using Manual Zip File (Compressed) download (wrong).

Here is how to deploy manually correctely:

1. Run this command

```sh
npm run build
```

Now a **build** folder will be created.

**2. Compress the content of this folder**
Not the content of the whole project.
You chnage directory to the **build** folder and Compress the content in side.

**3. Upload that compressed file Inside the build directory**
Now this should work just fine.
:)

Comment: Omg, this was such a huge headache. I can't believe there's no configuration as to "what" to use within the zip file you provide.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the an Access Denied error message too. The error went away when I followed [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa) described [in the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645821/20615798), but then I got [the white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025997/getting-an-access-denied-error-when-i-reload-my-react-app-on-aws-amplify#comment128333061_63645821) problem described above too.

Reviewing the steps I noticed the auto-complete for the "Destination Address" listed in the "Rewrites and redirects" settings was `/`.  When I tried using `/` as the "Destination Address" instead of `/index.html` I no longer got the white screen and got the expected page content.

Sharing what I found in case this helps others who are seeing a white screen after fixing the error with the rewrite rule described in the answers above.  (Note as of Nov 2022 the "Rewrites and redirects" setting page uses the wording "Target Address" instead of "Destination Address".)

Answer (score 3):

The correct rule should be like this:

```
Source address: </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>
Target address: /index.html
Status: 200
```

Comment: this only loads for me the index.html page and not the other routes and if i remove this.. the access denied error will come up again

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to deploy manually by uploading a .zip file. For some  reason, it was failing only with the .zip file I generated from a Mac, but not Windows.

Solution was to use a different compression software (i.e. I used Winzip for Mac).

Comment: thanks bro. got the same issue with __MACOSX folder

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I was zipping build folder, *but not the contents within the zip folder*.

Here is how I fixed it:

1. Run build command

   ```
   npm run build
   ```
2. Now a **build** folder will be created inside your project directory.
3. Open **build** folder.
4. Compress the contents of build folder, *and not build folder*.
5. Now upload this new zip created from sub files and folders from **build** folder.

App will run fine on AWS Amplify.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error,
I zipped the build folder first then uploaded it and got that error,
but when I just uploaded the folder without zipping it, it worked fine !! weird!!
in my application I used the port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and adding the redirect was not fixing the issue. I eventually remade my project with `create-react-app`, copied my old files over to it, and created a new amplify project with `amplify init`.

While rebuilding, it occurred to me that my old project was unnecessarily nested, which might have caused the build issue. My old project had the `.git` file outside the main project:

### Nested

```
clientProject/
└── .git
└── clientWebsite
    ├── amplify
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── public
    └── src
```

### Flat

```
clientProject/
└── clientWebsite
    ├── .git
    ├── amplify
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── public
    └── src
```

I believe this caused issues for me and Amplify's File server was failing to redirect to `index.html` when it was nested inside another folder. having a flat structure would have `index.html` in the base directory when running `npm run build` in production.